# Jenkins git fetch returned status code 143

Tags: linux, git, jenkins, ssh

I'm facing the problem with Jenkins with fetching git repo on Linux. I attach the stack trace. I have SSH gitlab connection configured with a private key and a passphrase. The configuration is made in Credentials/System/Global credentials (unrestricted). The path to the private key is /home/jenkins/.jenkins/secrets/my_private_key.pub. Owner and a group: jenkins:jenkins, where jenkins is the user making the installation. Permissions: 600.
The private key has been checked with the passphrase using ssh from the command line. The git fetch command used by jenkins has also been checked with command line. Both works.
Repository URL format is like:

```
git@github.com:org-name/project.git (short notation for ssh protocol)
```

Environment:

```
* CentOS 7 64 bit
* openjdk version "1.8.0_131" 64 bit
* Jenkins ver. 2.67
* Git client plugin 2.4.6Git plugin 3.3.0 (3.3.1 is not helping too)
* GIT server Plugin 1.7
* GitLab Plugin 1.4.5 (1.4.6 is not helping too)
* SCM API Plugin 2.1.1
* Credentials Plugin 2.1.14
* Jenkins is run directly
* Jenkins was installed with yum installer
* Browser: Google Chrome 59
* GitLab Community Edition 9.3.5
* git version 1.8.3.1
```

Stack trace:

```
started by user Jenkins Admin
Building in workspace /home/jenkins/.jenkins/workspace/my_project
 > git rev-parse --is-inside-work-tree # timeout=10
Fetching changes from the remote Git repository
 > git config remote.origin.url git@gitlab.repo:XYZ/docs/project.git # 
timeout=10
Cleaning workspace
 > git rev-parse --verify HEAD # timeout=10
No valid HEAD. Skipping the resetting
 > git clean -fdx # timeout=10
Fetching upstream changes from git@gitlab.repo:XYZ/docs/project.git
 > git --version # timeout=10
using GIT_SSH to set credentials 
 > git fetch --no-tags --progress git@gitlab.repo:XYZ/docs/project.git 
+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/* --depth=1
ERROR: Timeout after 10 minutes
ERROR: Error fetching remote repo 'origin'
hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Failed to fetch from git@gitlab.repo:XYZ/docs/project.git
at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.fetchFrom(GitSCM.java:809)
at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.retrieveChanges(GitSCM.java:1076)
at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.checkout(GitSCM.java:1107)
at hudson.scm.SCM.checkout(SCM.java:495)
at hudson.model.AbstractProject.checkout(AbstractProject.java:1212)
at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.defaultCheckout(AbstractBuild.java:560)
at jenkins.scm.SCMCheckoutStrategy.checkout(SCMCheckoutStrategy.java:86)
at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:485)
at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1735)
at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:97)
at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:415)
Caused by: hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Command "git fetch --no-tags --progress git@gitlab.repo:XYZ/docs/project.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/* --depth=1" returned status code 143:
stdout: 
stderr: 
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommandIn(CliGitAPIImpl.java:1903)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommandWithCredentials(CliGitAPIImpl.java:1622)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.access$300(CliGitAPIImpl.java:71)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl$1.execute(CliGitAPIImpl.java:348)
at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.fetchFrom(GitSCM.java:807)
... 11 more
ERROR: null
Finished: FAILURE
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. Running Jenkins as a service with systemctl resolved the problem, instead of running Jenkins with java -jar jenkins.war.

To give more details:
According to the documentation, Jenkins is started by

```
java -jar jenkins.war
```

And it was visible as running in the system when I checked it with:

```
ps aux | grep jenkins
```

However, on CentOS 7 the suggested way of running Jenkins is to run it as a daemon with systemctl command.
When I checked it with

```
sudo systemctl status jenkins.service
```

it was inactive.
So I started Jenkins with

```
sudo systemctl start jenkins.service
```

and it worked.